# How to keep div background behind an object / video

Tags: css, html, background

I have created a simple div in which i have a youtube video and then to the right i wish to write text. However when styling the div background only applies to the text, not the video object. Any pointers?

Code below -

HTML

```
<body>

<h1>PEACE TODAY</h1>

<div id="video">

<object id="youtube" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width:540px; height:300px;" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/VS4KoApcZHU&feature=relmfu">
</object>

<p> This is a youtube video </p>

</div>

</body>
```

CSS -

```
body {
    background-color: #B7DBFF;
    color: #006;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    margin:10%;
}

#video {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    padding:3%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#youtube {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: this can be viewed at http://newmedia.leeds.ac.uk/ug10/cs10mm/youtube.html

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: right;` or `float: left;` to the div:

```
#video {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;  
    float: right;
    padding:3%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add an `overflow: hidden;` to the div

```
#video {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    padding:3%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

so the "div" adjusts itself to what's inside